# Installing CUDA 8 .deb file error in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management, dpkg, cuda

I'm trying to unpack CUDA 8 on Ubuntu 16.04 by a `.deb` file. When I ran the command `sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-rc_8.0.27-1_amd64.deb` I got the following error:

```
(Reading database ... 172697 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-rc_8.0.27-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-rc (8.0.27-1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from 'cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-rc_8.0.27-1_amd64.deb' to decompressor pipe: unexpected end of file or stream
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-rc_8.0.27-1_amd64.deb (--install):
cannot copy extracted data for './var/cuda-repo-8-0-rc/cuda-cufft-cross-armhf-8-0_8.0.27-1_armhf.deb' to '/var/cuda-repo-8-0-rc/cuda-cufft-cross-armhf-8-0_8.0.27-1_armhf.deb.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-rc_8.0.27-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Did you try downloading a fresh copy of the deb? it looks like it may be corrupted

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you had the CUDA 8's beta version installed, and now you're trying to install the stable version. I had a similar issue.

Try using the `--force-overwrite` flag

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-rc_8.0.27-1_amd64.deb
```

on the next screen that follows, select `Y` to confirm overwrite.